# Получение строки из QLineEdit

Tags: qt, linux

Как можно получить строку из QLineEdit в QT в переменную типа char*, или как можно получить строку в QString, а затем преобразовать ее в char*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаете [строку из QLineEdit](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#text-prop) в QString:

```
// QLineEdit* myLineEdit;
QString text = myLineEdit->text();
```

Конвертируете в QByteArray и далее вытаскиваете нуль-терминальную строку, как описано [в этой статье на Nokia Developer](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_convert_a_qstring_to_char_and_vice_versa).